# adding controls to iPhone default camera

Tags: iphone, camera

When we capture an image from the default camera application, we can tweet,email,.. the photos.Is there any way to add our application in the same manner?

Regards,
Santosh

Comment: @sarvagnasantosh Example from the iPhone gallery, if we choose a photo, we can tweet,email,...This is possible in android but in iPhone i was not able to trace the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture image using the class `UIImagePicker` and store it in a `UIImageView` and then by adding `APIs` for twitter and what so ever, can share your captured image to others.

Comment: From application, we can do these things.But when you capture a photo from the iPhone camera  and not from the UIImage picker, by default image will be in the gallery. if you choose a photo from the gallery, from IOS5 onwards you can tweet ,email,...I i want to add my application in those option window what is the procedure?

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=iphone+gallery+tweet&um=1&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1250&bih=609&tbm=isch&tbnid=4mTL8miYKN5o0M:&imgrefurl=http://mashable.com/2011/10/18/ios-5-iphone-4-camera/&docid=mK_FP0x1nSKNxM&imgurl=http://8.mshcdn.com/wp-content/gallery/ios-5-for-iphone-4-photographers/1.png&w=283&h=425&ei=yJMvT7fcK8PRrQejtcHFDA&zoom=1

Comment: this is called as UIActionsheet. check this :http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/

Comment: Do one thing, once the image is loaded in a view, put a button called send and on its selection open the action sheet and in that you can load all these methods.

Comment: from the application we can do this.I want to do the same without using application.open iPhone --> photos --> select a photo and i want to add my application in default action sheet

Comment: I am writing a image manipulation application. in order to open my application,user need not click on my app. instead whenever he select photo from this phone gallery, i want to provide option something like "use with xxx".is this possible ? "xxx" is the app name

Comment: you mean that when that action sheet opens,it gives option of your app in the same??

Comment: No. It is not possible to add your app name in the default UIActionsheet.